# Foundation: Root variable in links not working for pages in subdirectories

Tags: handlebars.js, zurb-foundation

On the Foundation site I am working on, there is a dropdown topbar in a navigation partial that populates its links from several YML files in src/data (one per dropdown category). Each entry looks something like this:

```
link:
  text: "Example Link"
  url:  "beta/page2.html"
  external: false
```

The piece of the partial that generates each menu entry is as follows:

```
{{#each category}}
    <li><a href="{{#unless external}}{{root}}{{/unless}}{{url}}" {{#if external}}target="_blank"{{/if}}>{{text}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

The goal is for the link to be relative to the site's root if external is false, and used as-is (and open a new tab) if external is true.

The problem is that internal links don't seem to generate properly when the page I am navigating from is in a subdirectory. For example, if I am on `example.com/alpha/page1.html`, the menu link above points to `example.com/alpha/beta/page2.html` instead of `example.com/beta/page2.html`.

How can I change my code to properly generate the links for the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Inside the `{{#each}}` block, the Handlebars context changes, making variables like `{{root}}` only accessible through the parent context. The issue can be fixed by replacing `{{root}}` with `{{../root}}`.

From the [Handlebars documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/):

> The exact value that `../` will resolve to varies based on the helper that is calling the block. Using `../` is only necessary when context changes, so **children of helpers such as `each` would require the use of `../`** while children of helpers such as `if` do not.